# How to create modal signup form in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[Home Page Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmYzb.png)

[Modal Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiRqr.png)

I'm fairly new to Django so not sure how to solve my problem. I've created a simple UserCreationForm in a view function to sign up new users. However, I can't seem to display the form in a boostrap modal or in my index.html template.

I'm thinking by creating a separate view for the sign up form I need to have a separate template and url path to register new users. I'd like to have the sign up modal on the home page and not direct the user to a separate signup page.

```html
    {% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

    {% block navbar %}
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-primary nav-item" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          Sign Up
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join today</legend>
                  {{ form.as_p }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
              </form>
              <div class="border-top pt-3">
                <small class="text-muted">
                  Already have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </small>
              </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>        
    {% endblock navbar %}

    {% block content %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endblock content %}
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})  

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'form': form})
```

I would've thought that I can just display the Django form in the modal by calling the variable. When that didn't work I tried just displaying it in the body of the page as well, but that didn't work either. No errors were thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the `form` in all pages, you need to add the form (better call it `login_form` so it doesn't conflict with other forms you may have) to every View's context.

To avoid doing that repeatedly in all Views, Django has Context Processors. You include them in `settings.py`'s `TEMPLATES` variable. Example

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'myapp.context_processors.add_my_login_form',
        ],
    }]
```

Then, create a file called `context_processors.py` and add the `add_my_login_form()` function in there. The function returns the `login_form` to the request context of all requests.

```
def add_my_login_form(request):
    return {
        'login_form': LoginForm(),
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Few questions. Do I need to create a LogInForm class in order to initialize the object in context_processors.py? Does the context_processors.py go in the app directory or project directory? When calling the form variable in the template, do I use {{ form }} or {{ login_form }} ?

Answer (score 0):

try creating forms.py and create form first according to the models

- forms

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-django-form-class

- views

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_creating_views.htm

- try using crispy tags in html

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/api_templatetags.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot.